# widget test, testing a button with CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, testing, widget-test-flutter

I have two tests that after a click on a button I want to test if a CircularProgressIndicator will appear on the button.
The problem is after the tap and the `tester.pump()`, it can't find the CircularProgressIndicator causing the test to fail, I tried with `pumpAndSettle()` and also add a `Duration(seconds:x)` but got the same error

It's weird because the tests were ok before I update the flutter sdk to 1.22.0, upgrade my flutterFire packages and migrate to use the Android embbeding V2.

```js
testWidgets("Should show loading button when click on request button ",
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        _buildWidget(
          home: FinancialDialogBill(
            paymentId: "fakePaymentId",
            additionalValueType: AdditionalValueType.fee,
            billValues: billValues,
            installmentList: installments,
          ),
        ),
      );

      expect(find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButton), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButtonLoading), findsNothing);

      await tester.tap(find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButton));

      await tester.pump();

      expect(
          find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButtonLoading), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButton), findsNothing);

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but i ran into this issue as well, the shortest workaround i found i just to try/catch the timeout error...

```
try {
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
} catch (err) {}

expect(find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButtonLoading), findsOneWidget);
expect(find.byKey(financialDialogBillRequestButton), findsNothing);
```

Happy if it can help someone before a better solution is found.